# Cursor in SQL procedure not returning any values even though there are values to find

Tags: mysql, sql

Currently, I am using the cursor to fetch values from a table called SingleFinals and insert them into another table called Enters.
After the procedure is complete Enters still shows an empty set even though there are values to find. Even if I remove the if statement so as to add all values found, the Enters table is still an empty set.

Please let me know if you need any more information

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE insNewFinalEnters(
        evID DOUBLE,
        athID DOUBLE
)
COMMENT 'Insert new entry into Enters table'
BEGIN
DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
DECLARE eventID DOUBLE;
DECLARE sportID VARCHAR(9);
DECLARE insportID VARCHAR(9);
DECLARE curs CURSOR FOR SELECT e.sportID, e.eventID FROM Event e;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;

SELECT sportID FROM Event WHERE eventID = evID INTO insportID;

OPEN curs;

        read_loop: LOOP
                FETCH curs INTO sportID, eventID;
                IF done = 1 THEN
                        LEAVE read_loop;
                END IF;
                IF sportID = insportID AND eventID <> evID THEN
                        INSERT INTO Enters(eventID, sportID)
                        VALUES (eventID, athID);
                END IF;
        END LOOP read_loop;
CLOSE curs;

END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Curious why the types for the various ID's are `DOUBLE` instead of `INT`, and `VARCHAR` for ID's? ... Why not declare done as: `DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;`? ... Anyway, try with `SELECT sportID INTO insportID FROM Event WHERE eventID = evID;` ... if that still doesn't work, what is the table structure for `Enters`?

Comment: Yes, good point. I don't know why I initially created them as DOUBLE instead of INT. I'm going to change that. The teamID is VARCHAR because it is made up of part of the country of that team and the sport they play.
DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE; is defined that way because I'm working off the code that was given to me by my university. Would you suggest changing that also?
Thank you! That small change worked!!

Comment: Why do you even use a cursor instead of direct `INSERT ... SELECT ...` with an appropriate `WHERE` clause. Using cursors can be painfully slow compared to set based operations.

Comment: I had to demonstrate that I could use a cursor for university otherwise I would have much rathered using a SELECT statement.